# dpkg problem , can't uninstall or install the package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I tried to install virtualbox but something went wrong, and I force quitted the ubuntu software, now I can't remove the program and can't reinstall it and when I try to purge the program from the terminal I get the message that the package needs to be reinstalled.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package virtualbox-5.1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find
an archive for it.
```

Also when I try to reinstall using ubuntu software it just won't doing , an icon appears in the dock that says "waiting to install".

Comment: Please update your question with the commands you are running, and their output.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently reinstalling the package from terminal (and not ubuntu software)
solved the problem , I downloaded again the deb file from oracle and installed it using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.26-117224~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
```